# Instabot module returns 429 errors, too many requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api

I have done an Instagram bot using `instabot` module, but I have a problem. If I run my program from my laptop, it works. But if I run the exact same code on my linux server as a service, returns this error:

```
Aug 17 19:13:42 luca01 start.sh[31815]: 2021-08-17 19:13:42,777 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
Aug 17 19:13:42 luca01 start.sh[31815]: 2021-08-17 19:13:42,783 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
Aug 17 19:13:42 luca01 start.sh[31815]: 2021-08-17 19:13:42,964 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
Aug 17 19:13:42 luca01 start.sh[31815]: 2021-08-17 19:13:42,965 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
```

I have tried to wait some days but it still doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: the only suggestion that I can give you is to use a proxy for mask your public ip

Comment: My vps is located on another country and as you know I faced this problem.
Thanks for your advice.